# How to calculate partial derivative of an unknown function

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic

How can I force Mathematica to calculate symbolically the partial derivative of a function `u[x,y]` with respect to a variable `z = f(x, y)`, where f(x, y) is known?

`u` is a function, defined on reals, taking real values. Same thing holds for `f`.

I want to try different changes of variables in PDEs. An example of what I'm trying to achieve and why it's failing:

```
z = 2*x + y
```

> 2 x + y

```
D[u[x, y], z]
```

> General::ivar: 2 x+y is not a valid variable. >>
>
> D[u[x, y], 2*x + y]

**EDIT**: It appears I have failed to convey the essence of the question.

I am not asking *how* to solve a PDE with Mathematica. I am asking how, given a transformation of the original variables, to calculate the partial derivatives with respect to the new variables. The PDE part is merely some context as to why I want to do this.

Comment: In general, the quantity you ask for is not well-defined. For example, for `z = x + I y`, the  derivative of `f(x,y)` w.r.t. `z` exists only for holomorphic functions, which is a strong requirement. So, you have to first define exactly what you look for.

Comment: I am talking about functions, defined only in the real domain, however I am not assuming that `f` will always be linear in `x` and `y`.

Comment: If you start with two variables, then a transformation is specified completely only if you have *two* equations defining two new variables. It also has to be locally invertible.

Comment: @Jens I agree, however after defining a transformation, making sure it is locally invertible, you have to calculate the partial derivatives with respect to the new variables. This is the part that I want Mathematica to do, since it is extremely error-prone, especially with higher-order derivatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to belisarius' concrete answer, here is a more symbolic formulation:

If `u` and `v` are the new variables and the transformation functions are known to be

```
{x[u, v], y[u, v]}
```

then the set of partial derivatives of `f` with respect to `u` and `v` (i.e., the gradient) is

```
D[f[x, y], {{x, y}}].D[{x[u, v], y[u, v]}, {{u, v}}]
```

> $\left\{ \\
>  f^{(1,0)}(x,y) x^{(1,0)}(u,v)+f^{(0,1)}(x,y)y^{(1,0)}(u,v), \\  
>    f^{(1,0)}(x,y) x^{(0,1)}(u,v)+f^{(0,1)}(x,y)y^{(0,1)}(u,v)\\
> \right\}$

Comment: Nice answer. I wonder how to format that last line in a more reasonable way :(

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is what you want. Anyway:

Suppose we define new coordinates:

```
{w == x + y, z == x - y}
```

Now:

```
ClearAll[f];
sol = Solve[{w == x + y, z == x - y}, {x, y}];
FullSimplify@D[f[x, y] /. sol[[1]], z]
```

Let's try it:

```
f[x_, y_] := (x + y)^2
FullSimplify@D[f[x, y] /. sol[[1]], z]
(* 0 *)
FullSimplify@D[f[x, y] /. sol[[1]], w]
(* 2 w *)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Dt`.

```
Dt[u[x, y], f[x, y]]

(* Dt[y, f[x, y]]*Derivative[0, 1][u][x, y] + Dt[x, f[x, y]]*Derivative[1, 0][u][x, y] *)
```

Comment: Now the big question is what `Dt[y, f[x, y]]` means. Try defining `f[x_, y_] := x + y` and see what happens. Basically the same as the error in the original question.

Comment: Good point. Why should `Dt` differentiate correctly w.r.t. `f[x,y]` but not w.r.t. `Plus[x,y]`? Anyway, the original question - i.e. the partial derivative of a function `u[x,y]` w.r.t. `f[x, y]` - is answered by `Dt[u[x, y], f[x, y]]`.